# Sublime Text browser preview, JQuery not running

Tags: jquery, sublimetext

I'm trying to set up a page with skrollr to use parallax. Everything works fine on CodePen for example but nothing works when I set up my page on Sublime Text and preview it.

Is there something preventing JQuery from running when doing a preview? Is there something wrong in my head tag that I am missing?

I have tried different URLs and using JQuery locally but nothing does the trick.

```
<head>
  <title>Parallax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="birds.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="birds.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: what does our friendly console tell us?

Comment: It says that "$ is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
  <title>Parallax</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="birds.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="birds.js"></script>
</head>
```

Can you try this one?

Answer (score 2):

It could be down to the fact you have your JS library declared before the CDN libraries?

Have it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="birds.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes...That was exactly the problem. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Call the Jquery before skrollr and try:

```
<head>
  <title>Parallax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="birds.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="birds.js"></script>

</head>
```